# Ansible - omit parameter in list of dictionary

Tags: ansible

I know about the omit filter but I'm not able to get to work when it's in a list of dictionaries.

I want it so that if for example, the published_port variable is not defined then the publish parameter is omitted

```
- name: test
  community.docker.docker_swarm_service:
    name: myservice
    image: alpine
    publish:
      - published_port: "{{ published_port | default(omit) }}"
        target_port: "{{ target_port | default(omit) }}"
```

The error I get is: "missing required arguments: published_port, target_port found in publish". I know it's something to do with it being a list but not sure how to get around this issue.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the list. If you end up omitting the two, you end up wih a list with one empty element, so your `publish` ends up invalid. You have to omit `publish` itself in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because, when your two variables are both undefined, you end up creating a list with one empty element. But what you should really do in this case is to omit the **whole** `published` parameter.

You can achieve this thanks to a [inline if expression](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#if-expression), assessing if both variables are undefined, ending up omitting the whole parameter.

Here would be an example playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - set_fact: 
        docker: 
          name: myservice
          image: alpine
          publish: >- 
            {{ 
              [{
                'published_port': published_port | default(omit), 
                'target_port': target_port | default(omit)
              }]
              if published_port is defined or target_port is defined else omit 
            }}

    - debug:
        var: docker
```

Mind that I am defining neither `published_port` nor `target_port` in this playbook.

- Now, if I run it like that, I will get the recap:

  ```
  PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************

  TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost]

  TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => 
    docker:
      image: alpine
      name: myservice

  PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
  localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
  ```
- If I run it adding [`-e 'published_port=42'`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-at-runtime), I will get the recap:

  ```
  PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************

  TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost]

  TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => 
    docker:
      image: alpine
      name: myservice
      publish:
      - published_port: '42'

  PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
  localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
  ```
- If I run it adding [`-e 'target_port=43'`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-at-runtime), I will get the recap:

  ```
  PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************

  TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost]

  TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => 
    docker:
      image: alpine
      name: myservice
      publish:
      - target_port: '43'

  PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
  localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
  ```
- And, finally, if I run it adding [`-e 'published_port=42 target_port=43'`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-at-runtime), I will get the recap:

  ```
  PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************

  TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost]

  TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => 
    docker:
      image: alpine
      name: myservice
      publish:
      - published_port: '42'
        target_port: '43'

  PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
  localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
  ```

Which fixes your issue.